# Windows open office combining formulas

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

I'm using this formula

```
=Match(b8;'sheet2'.b1:b100;0)
```

Let's say it will give a result of 52

Then I want it to show the value of `sheet2.g52`, or maybe use it in `vlookup` like this

```
=Vlookup(b8;'sheet2'.b(formula here):b100;0)
```

So I won't have to this manually

```
=Vlookup(b8;'sheet2'.b52:b100;0)
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do in the formula.  If you just want to use the result as part of an address, look at the INDIRECT function.

Comment: Build (concatenate) a string and use as arg to INDIRECT(), yes.